# Do I need to search for patents which are not yet published?

Tags: prior-art, search

I am doing prior art searching. I want to to know whether I need to search for patents which are not yet published. If so, how do I do this?

A related question is: Can I search all patents which are filed today (or less than 18 months ago)?

Answer (score 3):

Patent applications which are not published will not be available for search.

Refer to this link to understand on how to conduct a prior art search: http://www.invntree.com/blogs/how-conduct-patent-search

Answer (score 0):

no, patents which are not published are not available for search

Answer (score 0):

Patents that aren't yet published aren't searchable unless you're a patent examiner. As an outside searcher, you're limited to issued patents and published applications (in addition to non-patent literature, e.g., everything on the internet).

No, you can't search all patents that were filed today. You have to wait until they are published.

Comment: Patent examiners can't look at applications that are not published.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of filing you wont be able to search it, best way is to file a patent and do a weekly search with already designed keyword till 20 month you will eventually reach to cover all prior art till filing.